# File info pull from sub folders only 2-3 levels deep

Tags: vba, excel, namespaces, subdirectory, createobject

I currently have a code that will allow the user to pick a folder and then the code will pull the file information for the files in that folder but not for any files in sub folders. I have 7 levels of subfolders containing about 140,000 files. I was wondering if there is a way for me to pull only pull the info of files in subfolder level 2-3 not solely 1 and not from all 7 levels. Thank you for your help.

I don't think the "pasting formula in column 3" section will be relevant for this problem.

The sections that probably matter are "Picking a folder" and "Running through each file in the selected folder"

```
Sub Compile3()
  Dim oShell As Object
  Dim oFile As Object
  Dim oFldr As Object
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim iCol As Integer
  Dim vArray As Variant
  vArray = Array(10, 0, 1, 156, 2, 4, 144, 146, 183, 185)

  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  Dim iRow As Long
   iRow = Cells.find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
   lRow = iRow
'----------------------Picking a folder-------------------------------------


  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .title = "Select the Folder..."
    If .Show Then
      Set oFldr = oShell.Namespace(.SelectedItems(1))
      With oFldr

      'Don't show update on the screen until the macro is finished
      Application.EnableEvents = False

'---------------Column header information-----------------------------------

        For iCol = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
          If lRow = 2 Then
            Cells(lRow, iCol + 4) = .getdetailsof(.items, vArray(iCol))
          Else
            Cells(lRow, iCol + 4) = "..."
          End If             
        Next iCol
'---------------Running through each file in the selected folder------------   
        For Each oFile In .items
          lRow = lRow + 1

          For iCol = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)                   
             Cells(lRow, iCol + 4) = .getdetailsof(oFile, vArray(iCol))    
          Next iCol
 ' ---------------Pasting formula in column 3 -----------------------------             
               If lRow < 4 Then
                        Cells(lRow, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$B$10,2,FALSE),""User Not Found"")"

           Else
                    Cells((lRow - 1), 3).Copy
                    Cells(lRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Cells(lRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False                                       

           End If              
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------            

        Next oFile
      End With
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
  End With  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code to work with arrays and use a recursive function to return the folder file information.

---

```
Sub ProcessFolder()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim Target As Range

    FolderPath = getFileDialogFolder

    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    getFolderItems FolderPath, results
    CompactResults results

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("C3", .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
        Set Target = .Range("C3")
        Set Target = Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, 4)
        Target.Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
        Target.Offset(1, -1).Resize(UBound(results) - 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$B$10,2,FALSE),""User Not Found"")"
    End With

End Sub

Sub CompactResults(ByRef results As Variant)
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim x As Long, x1 As Long, y As Long, y1 As Long

    ReDim data(1 To UBound(results) + 1, 1 To UBound(results(0)) + 1)

    For x = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        x1 = x1 + 1
        y1 = 0
        For y = LBound(results(x)) To UBound(results(x))
            y1 = y1 + 1
            data(x1, y1) = results(x)(y)
        Next
    Next

    results = data
End Sub

Function getFileDialogFolder() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the Folder..."
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            getFileDialogFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

Sub getFolderItems(FolderPath As String, ByRef results As Variant, Optional MaxLevels As Long = 1, Optional oShell As Object, Optional Level As Long)
    Dim oFile As Object, oFldr As Object

    If oShell Is Nothing Then
        ReDim results(0)
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    End If

    If Not IsEmpty(results(UBound(results))) Then ReDim Preserve results(UBound(results) + 1)

    Set oFldr = oShell.Namespace(CStr(FolderPath))

    results(UBound(results)) = getFolderFileDetailArray(oFldr.Self, oFldr)
    results(UBound(results))(1) = oFldr.Self.Path
    For Each oFile In oFldr.Items
        ReDim Preserve results(UBound(results) + 1)
        If oFldr.getDetailsOf(oFile, 2) = "File folder" Then
            If Level < MaxLevels Then
                getFolderItems oFile.Path, results, MaxLevels, oShell, Level + 1
            End If
        End If
        results(UBound(results)) = getFolderFileDetailArray(oFile, oFldr)
    Next oFile

End Sub

Function getFolderFileDetailArray(obj As Object, oFldr As Object) As Variant
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim vDetailSettings As Variant
    vDetailSettings = Array(10, 0, 1, 156, 2, 4, 144, 146, 183, 185)

    For iCol = LBound(vDetailSettings) To UBound(vDetailSettings)
        vDetailSettings(iCol) = oFldr.getDetailsOf(obj, vDetailSettings(iCol))
    Next iCol

    getFolderFileDetailArray = vDetailSettings

End Function
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. This looks interesting but it didn't work. I got an error on the array line:

`results = Application.Transpose(results)`

I'm also not positive your code will do what I want. It may not be possible. As mentioned above  I don't just want a "deep dive" and I don't just want the first level. (I have like 7 levels of folders with a total of 140,000 files) I only want to grab say level 2-3 info. (over even better have the user determine how many levels deep)

Comment: So it doesn't seem to be working. I already have a code that pulls the file information of the first folder just fine. I want to know if I can grab specific levels of a folderpath. Does this code do that?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm not sure why it won't work for you.

Comment: Where in your code do you determine how deep the folder/file pull goes?

Comment: So I opened a new excel workbook and pasted exactly what you have above in a module there. I connected the `Sub ProcessFolder()` to a button. When I click it it pulls up the folder select window. When I select a folder and hit okay nothing happens

Comment: thank you so much for this solution. I've modified it to work for me. I was wondering if you have any suggestions on making it faster? I have to filter through quite a few files (140,000) and I'm running on a laptop with weak processing power

Comment: Also I don't want to print the titles of the columns everytime I click the button. How can I get rid of that feature

Comment: I updated `Sub ProcessFolder()` .  Changing the value of `RemoveTiles`  will give you the option of printing the titles.

Comment: What did you do to update `Sub ProcessFolder()` because now the username is printing all over the place?

Comment: Yeah the original `Sub ProcessFolder()` worked great except for that titles line would screw up my formula and the `Const RemoveTiles As Boolean = True` didn't remove the titles and messed up the code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Basically this line of code `Target.Offset(1, -1).Resize(UBound(results) - 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$B$10,2,FALSE),""User Not Found"")"` references the wrong cells for `D3` as the Sub sorts through the different files. I've also added: `Target.Offset(1, 13).Resize(UBound(results) - 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(LOOKUP(REPT(""z"",255),MID(E3,SEARCH({""dw"",""lex"",""tex"",""qex"",""qnxr"",""rex""},E3),{6,7,7,7,8,7})),""Not Found"")"`

Comment: Is there a way I could just share the file with you? It would probably be easier for you to look at. Sorry I'm a little new to this whole stackoverflow thing

Comment: Essentially my header will be set and does not need to be run by the code and I'd like the code to just start in cell C3.

Comment: We are getting so close. I have headers in columns C2 to U2. The current code puts the data starting in C3 but it deletes the headers in columns C2 to I2. Also the relative reference for the formula is off because the first line of data the the code prints is the path of the folder selected. If the code could just not print that path way then the relative reference in the formula will sink up with the correct row

Comment: I also want to be able to run the code multiple times. Is there a way to have it start the code at the next available row?

Comment: Okay everything is fixed except for the issue above ^ I want to run the macro multiple time and have the data fill into the next available row

Answer (score 0):

The [file system object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx) can do this for you.

In this example, the code returns every subfolder on your C:\ drive.

```
' Returns every folder under the C:\.
Sub CrawlFolder()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject     ' Access the Windows file system.
    Dim folder As folder            ' Used to loop over folders.


    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    For Each folder In fso.GetFolder("C:\").SubFolders

        Debug.Print folder.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

To view the results make sure you've turned the `Immediate` window on (*View* >> *Immediate Window*).

To use the file system object you'll need to add a reference (*Tools* >> *References* >> *Windows Script Host Object Model*).

You can add a second `For Each Loop` to view the files:

```
' Returns every folder under the C:\.
Sub CrawlFolder()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject     ' Access the Windows file system.
    Dim folder As folder            ' Used to loop over folders.
    Dim file As file                ' Used to loop over files.

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    For Each folder In fso.GetFolder("C:\").SubFolders

        For Each file In folder.Files

            Debug.Print file.Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've looked at using the `FileSystemObject` the thing is that grabs all subfolders in the `C:\..` drive and it grabs the second and third set of subfolders down from those subfolder. Your file loop will then grab all subsequent files.

I only want to pull the first and second set of files and subfolders not the 3rd or 4th set of subfolders down from the initial `C:\.` drive

Comment: This code will only return the first level of folders (tested Win7, Excel 2010 just now).  It's true that `fso` can be used to deep-dive.  That's normally achieved using a method called [recursion](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/recursionandfso.htm), which I haven't used in this example.

Comment: right you can modify it either way but I want to do something in the middle. Not a "deep dive" as you put it and not just the first level. (I have like 7 levels of folders with a total of 140,000 files) I only want to grab say level 2-3 info